# Lightning Web Component passing the particular value and retrieving the data in other component

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, lwc-wire-adapter

Hi I have a requirement in which i am passing the data from parent to child component and need to fetch the particular data in the track property in child component.

```
Parent Component.

    @track info = [];

    Info.push({
      name:"Priya",
      Age:"12",
      School:"Asvidya",
      City:"Delhi"
      });

     <C-child info = {Info} ></child>

Child Component.
@track priyaAge;
 @track informationgirl = [];

    @api
    get info() {
        return this.informationgirl;
    }

    set info(value) {
       this.informationgirl = value.detail;
    }
```

As per req i just want to pick out the age of priya from the incoming data and store in the @track priyaAge in child component.

Comment: Why are you passing an array if you need a single value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see an example in the [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/3AI8WisC7/2/edit)

in the parent component :

```
<c-child info={info}></c-child>
```

```
@track info = {
      name:"Priya",
      Age:"12",
      School:"Asvidya",
      City:"Delhi"
      };
```

In the child component

```
   @track priyaAge;
    @track informationgirl = [];

    @api
    get info() {
        return this.informationgirl;
    }

    set info(value) {

        this.informationgirl = value.detail;
        this.priyaAge = value.Age
    }
```